# Skype/Spotify Installation Error: Cannot Install libssl1.0.0:i386

Tags: linux, openssl, skype, deepin

OpenSSL has been giving me a lot of gripe lately with some pieces of software such as spotify and skype. I include both apps because I think it's the same issue causing both to stop installing, although the error log is somewhat different in both.

Spotify:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     spotify-client : Depends: libnss3-1d but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: libavcodec53 but it is not installable or
                                  libavcodec52 but it is not installable or
                                  libavcodec-extra-53 but it is not installable or
                                  libavcodec-extra-52 but it is not installable
                      Recommends: libavformat53 but it is not installable or
                                  libavformat52 but it is not installable or
                                  libavformat-extra-53 but it is not installable or
                                  libavformat-extra-52 but it is not installable
```

Skype:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype-bin:i386 : Depends: libssl1.0.0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Doing my own research the solution I found to the broken packages issue was to use 'sudo apt-get -f install' but that just returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as this is kinda a last resort after trying solutions to similar problems for a number of hours.

EDIT 3:
Result of sudo apt-get install libnss3=2:3.17.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnss3 : Depends: libnss3-nssdb but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

EDIT 2:
Result of apt-cache policy libnss3:

```
libnss3:
  Installed: 2:3.17.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Candidate: 2:3.17.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 2:3.17.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:3.17.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 0
        400 http://ca1.packages.linuxdeepin.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        400 http://ca1.packages.linuxdeepin.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2:3.15.4-1ubuntu7 0
        400 http://ca1.packages.linuxdeepin.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

EDIT:
Result of sudo apt-get install libnss3-1d:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnss3-1d : Depends: libnss3 (= 2:3.17.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) but 2:3.17.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Output of apt-cache policy libnss3-1d:

```
libnss3-1d:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:3.17.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Version table:
     2:3.17.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 0
        400 http://ca1.packages.linuxdeepin.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        400 http://ca1.packages.linuxdeepin.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2:3.15.4-1ubuntu7 0
        400 http://ca1.packages.linuxdeepin.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Package
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a version of `libssl1.0.0:amd64` installed which isn't available in the Deepin repositories; this prevents installation of `libssl1.0.0:i386` from the repositories since the versions must match.

To fix this, you can either find the corresponding version of `libssl1.0.0:i386` (1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.8), if you know where you got `libssl1.0.0:amd64` from, or you can downgrade `libssl1.0.0:amd64` to the version in the archive. The following command should work to do the latter:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0:amd64=1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.7
```

Once the package has been downgraded, you can install `libssl1.0.0:i386`:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0:i386
```

If Deepin is tracking Ubuntu Trusty Tahr (14.04), after you've got your system working again you should probably install version 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.11, which you can download from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl; but you'd be better off asking Deepin to upgrade their version...

The same applies to `libnss3-1d`: you have a version of `libnss3` which isn't in the repositories. To fix this:

```
sudo apt-get install libnss3=2:3.17.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 libnss3-nssdb=2:3.17.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
```

will downgrade `libnss3` and `libnss3-nssdb` to the repositories' version, then

```
sudo apt-get install libnss3-1d
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Run as root in a console (or maybe sudo the command. Anyways,)
2. `sudo apt-get clean`
3. `sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0`
4. Try installing Skype and Spotify again.

Comment: sudo apt-get clean returned nothing.
The libssl install returned this:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libssl1.0.0 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Installing skype and spotify returned the same errors as in the OP. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Hopefully someone can give a solution. Maybe reinstalling it might help.

Comment: Yeah I really didn't want to resort to it as I've got my system all set up the way I wanted now but oh well, if it comes to it.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue myself installing postgres. I had to add:

`deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security wheezy/updates main`

to my `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

(Don't forget `sudo apt-get update`)